# bizarre break point failure

Tags: c#, breakpoints

When I set the debugger on for a task, and then press F5 to continue, it works. But when I don't set any debugger points, then the task either gives me an error or does an infinite loop.
Also,
I have found that if I have breakpoints set, but when I disable the breakpoints it will succeed, but when I remove the breakpoints the task fails.
Do I have to disable break points for it succeeds in c#?

Comment: Could you show the code? It sounds to be some artifact due to the break point.

Comment: I cant quite do that. but the debugger is set on a website that I make in the code

Comment: Try outputting the information that you are trying to see to a debug log file or via MessageBox.Show(). This way you might be able to figure out what is going on that breakpoints are making it work

Comment: the thing is i dont want to use the debugger and i want working without it. When i try working without it, it either goes into infinite loop or fails but as i said when i disable it instead it works. The question is do i actually have to disable the debugger for it to work? since i dont want it there in the first place

Comment: It's a bit hard to help unless you post the code and what the error is, a stab in the dark I would say it sounds like a race condition that is prevented when you hit a breakpoint.

Comment: by task fail i mean it doesnt output the data at all

Comment: but with it disabled it does output the task, does it have to be that way?

Comment: @FaizSaiyed No it doesn't have to be that way, any code that only works if you break in a debugger on a certain line is broken, if you post the code and explain the error then maybe we can help.

Comment: I find most problems with the debugger go away with a reboot.